# SQL : SELECT something and exclude some LIKE values

Tags: sql, oracle

In table dba_users I have the following values in USERNAME column:

```
WZHBIJ
LALA
LOLO
MMISROK1
MMISROK2
MMISROK3
MMISROK4
MMISROK5
MMISROK6
WZHMEJ
```

I want to write a SELECT statement that would return me only `WZHBIJ` and `WZHMEJ`, but I MUST use "NOT IN".

So, I would like to stick to the conception using NOT IN :

```
 SELECT username FROM dba_users where username NOT IN ('LALA','LOLO') OR username NOT IN LIKE 'MMISROK%'
```

Comment: Have you tried `... NOT IN (SELECT username FROM dba_users WHERE username LIKE 'MMISROK%')`

Comment: You don't want to use LIKE also?

Comment: There is no `NOT IN LIKE`, rather `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: Also worth remembering that using negative statements with an OR can give you results that aren't immediately intuitive. For example, change the 'NOT IN LIKE' in your query to 'NOT LIKE' (so it is valid SQL) and you wont limit the results at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT IN` twice:

```
select u.*
from dba_users u
where u.username not in (select u2.username
                         from dba_users u2
                         where u2.username not in ('WZHBIJ', 'WZHMEJ')
                        );
```

I don't understand the purpose of such exercises.

Comment: You can further simplify this query by saying `select * from dba_users where username in ('WZHBIJ', 'WZHMEJ') and username not in (select 'X' from dual)`. Clearly no purpose in this exercise...

Answer (score 1):

if you must only use `NOT IN` you can try:

```
SELECT username
FROM dba_users
WHERE username NOT IN (
        'LALA'
        ,'LOLO'
        )
    AND username NOT IN (
        SELECT username
        FROM dba_users
        WHERE username LIKE 'MMISROK%'
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your little magic, it works exactly as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give another 'flavour' this time using a CTE;

```
WITH sub_query
 AS (SELECT username
     FROM   dba_users
     WHERE  username LIKE 'MMIS%'
        OR  username LIKE 'L%L%')
SELECT *
FROM   dba_users du
WHERE  mu.username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM sub_query)
```